# How to quench unreacted sodium azide from reaction mixture?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

The reaction involved synthesis of azide formation from alkyl bromide in DMF using sodium azide. After the reaction has taken place, how do I quench the unreacted sodium azide from the reaction mixture?

Comment: Why do you want to "quench" it?

Comment: I happen to read about safety precautions regarding handling, using sodium azide. So I came across few web pages, where they warn you not to dispose it into the drain but try to quench it. So I thought about to get an opinion on this. Anyways  I took my reaction mixture, extracted in ethyl acetate/water. And it worked well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Excess of sodium azide can be quenched using nitrous acid.

$$\ce{2NaNO2 + H2SO4 → 2HNO2 + Na2SO4}$$

$$\ce{2NaN3 + 2HNO2 → 3N2 + 2NO + 2NaOH}$$

For further reading, Click [here](http://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Analytical_Chemistry/Lab_Techniques/Reagent_Specific_Hazards/Sodium_Azide).